# MySql find all rows where data contains less than four characters

Tags: mysql

How would I properly write this sql-english query:

"SELECT zip FROM tblContacts WHERE [the number of characters in zips is less or equal than 4]".

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming `zip` is a string:

```
WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(zip) <= 4
```

should work.

**Edit**: originally there was some confusion as to whether the desired comparison was `<`, `<=`, or `>`, but now the Q's been edited to clarify, so I've edited my A accordingly.

Comment: Yeah.  I couldn't find an "whoops -- need to edit the post" button.

Comment: @D.A.@, the `edit` link is below and to the left of your post, just below the tags "buttons" that say `mysql` and `query` -- anyway, now editing my answer since you've now clarified it "less than or equal to four", thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT zip FROM tblContacts WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(zip) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there must be a better way, but...:

```
SELECT zip FROM tblContacts WHERE zip LIKE '_' OR zip LIKE '__' OR zip LIKE '___' OR zip LIKE '____';
```